# Is it possible to use Google Maps disconnected from the Internet?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been tasked with building an offline web application that will display maps and also display locations and routes of objects.  The requirements are that it run in a web browser, but it will run on a disconnected laptop.  It will be receiving continuous, real-time map coordinates data and continuously updating the location of objects and also display historical route data.  Is it possible to somehow use Google Maps for this?  I know that Google recently announced support for offline maps - but I got the feeling that was specifically for the Android OS and also specifically for mobile devices.  If not, Google Maps - does anyone have any suggestions for which mapping technology, API or software would be best for this type of application?

Comment: How exactly would one plan on getting the information from Google if the laptop was not connected to the Internet?  I'm a bit confused by this requirement.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was some sort of disconnected Google Maps product that you could install and still use the Google Maps API - only instead of connecting to the Google servers, it connects to a local version of the maps.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - you'd have to have the whole suite of maps on your local device before you could say it was disconnected.  I did look into it a bit, and there's not an exact date for when Google's API will support this.  Of course, it also implies that the device will have to be connected to the Internet at *some* point before it can take advantage of "Offline Mode".

Comment: For now you can't prefetch or cache the maps for online use. See 10.1.3.b of the [terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

Comment: @Makoto: Is there really a statement that the API will ever support this?

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not possible.  You have to load the maps dynamically from the web and you are not allowed to cache information (*you can cache a small amount of information temporarily, but you cannot do bulk or mass downloads).

See Section 10.1.3 of the terms of service:

http://goo.gl/HX3Uj